Which PCA results are correct?
I aim to find which directions in my data have "vary greatly". To do that, I understand a method called PCA, which uses the eigenvectors of the covariant matrix to find them.
I used different implementations to calculate the principal component analysis.
matrix = np.array([
    [-0.5, 0.5],
    [1.5, 1.5]
])
covariance_matrix = np.cov(matrix[:,0], matrix[:,1])
eigen_values, eigen_vectors = np.linalg.eig(covariance_matrix)

print("eigen_vectors: ", eigen_vectors)
print("Eigen values: ", eigen_values)

The output is
eigen_vectors:  [[ 0.89442719 -0.4472136 ]
 [ 0.4472136   0.89442719]]
Eigen values:  [2.5 0. ]

I used also a javascript library to calculate it:
const output = PCA.getEigenVectors([
    [-0.5, 0.5],
    [1.5, 1.5]
])
console.log(output)

which output is
[
  {
    eigenvalue: 1.2499999999999998,
    vector: [ 0.8944271909999157, 0.4472135954999579 ]
  },
  {
    eigenvalue: 0,
    vector: [ 0.4472135954999579, -0.8944271909999159 ]
  }
]

While I expect different decimals due to internal language implementations, I also have other signs and eigenvalues.
Why does this happen? Which results are correct (or more accurate) for my case and why?
Or are both results valid, and can I use them in my case?

Why are you trying to use two completely different programming languages to solve a problem? What is your real problem? Are you just trying to do math inside of a programming context for fun?

It literally is the first sentence of the question: I have to understand in which direction my data "expands" more. If my data is the stars in the Milky Way, it is clear in which direction the points "vary greatly".

So which programming language are you using to process this data? Python, or JavaScript? Please pick one for the purposes of your question (and for the benefit of you finding a solution outside of the context of Stack Overflow, as well).


That JavaScript library might be using a different normalization for the covariance matrix.

You can use ml-pca for JS, if you have to use JS. Otherwise, I'd just use python.

The covariance matrix is scaled by the number of observations minus one (N - 1) for an "unbiased" estimate. In some libraries, the cov matrix might be scaled differently (by N instead), leading to a different eigenvalue scaling. For instance, you can scale the eigenvalues from the JS implementation to match the Python output by multiplying the eigenvalues by 2 (1.25 * 2 = 2.5).


JS
const P = require("ml-pca").PCA;

const data = [
  [-0.5, 0.5],
  [1.5, 1.5],
];

const pca = new P(data);
console.log(pca.getEigenvalues(), pca.getEigenvectors());


Prints
[ 2.5000000000000004, 0 ] Matrix {
  [
     0.89443  0.44721
     0.44721 -0.89443
  ]
  rows: 2
  columns: 2
}


Python

import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([
    [-0.5, 0.5],
    [1.5, 1.5]
])
covariance_matrix = np.cov(matrix[:, 0], matrix[:, 1])
eigen_values, eigen_vectors = np.linalg.eig(covariance_matrix)

# eigen_values /= 2

print("eigen_vectors: ", eigen_vectors)
print("Eigen values: ", eigen_values)
# help(np.linalg.eig)
# help(np.cov)


Prints
eigen_vectors:  [[ 0.89442719 -0.4472136 ]
 [ 0.4472136   0.89442719]]
Eigen values:  [2.5 0. ]



Notes:

The eigenvalues represent the variance provided by each component. A higher value means a greater variance along that component.

You can look into the statistics of your data and see whether the eigenvalues align with your expectations. Does the variance provided by the principal components make sense given the nature of your data?

Make sure that the proper normalization or scaling have been performed. If not, you can scale it by any factor to get meaningful analysis.



You are right: multiplying the covariant matrix by 0.5 aligns the results. Anyway, this factor changes so much that my initial aim (which directions in my data have "vary greatly") isn't achieved. How can I know if the result is "good" or if I have to use a factor of the covariant matrix?
